# How to open interactive python terminal with initial code?

Tags: python, windows, terminal

Is there any way to open an active, interactive python terminal that will automatically run my initial ~10 lines of code?

My specific use (which will probably be needed to clarify the question) is that I have a Microsoft SQL Server that it takes just a little too long to bother opening SSMS when I just want to quickly find the ID for a record or something.

What I've found myself doing is opening a python terminal (just have python pinned to the start menu), and copy-pasting in ~10 lines of code from a text file I leave open (import sqlalchemy, import pandas, set driver and connection string). Then I'll actually type in whatever I'm looking for (`pd.read_sql('Select * from table where x = y'`) and getting the name of my record.

I've no doubt that there are plenty of completely better solutions to viewing data in a database effectively, but I'm hoping that I can easily improve my current (albeit janky) worthflow until I get around to a real solution. Plus, just seems like a useful thing to do.

Comment: I think you can use crontab, or make a exec and add it to you windows scheduler, the latter I don't think can be scheduled for every 10 mins but you can try it out.

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava, did you mean to comment on another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`python -i script_with_first_10_lines.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter):

> When a script file is used, it is sometimes useful to be able to run the script and enter interactive mode afterwards. This can be done by passing [`-i`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) before the script.

This will run your script, then stay in interactive mode so you can run more code by typing it in.

Comment: as a little addition for myself, I created a shortcut that runs `python -i script.py` and then pinned that shortcut to my start menu. so now i just have that start-menu button and boom, ready to go.

based it off of this article, but changed the command to be python instead of cmd: https://winaero.com/pin-a-batch-file-to-the-start-menu-or-taskbar-in-windows-10/